# How to embed one ember application in another ember application?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, embed, add-on, ember-addon

I am having a small ember application and I need to embed this into another ember application . How can I do this embedding ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't embed ember app inside another ember app. but you can embed ember app in other frameworks or websites.(I may be wrong, in my earlier attempt I failed)
But you have got few options to consider,
1. You can consider writing [ember engine](http://ember-engines.com/)
2. You can write addon and use it in your ember app

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try these options.

Comment: How to embed ember application in other frameworks or websites ?

Comment: You can include the index.html code in your website

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest using an `iframe`, and searching through the available addons, I've come across https://github.com/ming-codes/ember-iframe-app I've never used this library, but it looks promising

Comment: How to put 2 apps in production ?

Comment: I'd recommend Ember Engines over this approach in the interests of not needing to load your Ember libraries twice ...